# Incorrect string value: '\xE7\x9A' for column 'message' at row 1

Tags: mysql

Please help me with an issue we are getting when storing a string value using MySQL prepared statement.

> Incorrect string value: '\xE7\x9A' for column 'message' at row 1

We are storing incoming emails into a MySQL database. The database column is defined as `utf8mb4` as you can see from the table below and hence I am puzzled why this error.

```sql
CREATE TABLE `messages` (
  `mid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `message` varchar(16000) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT '',
  `type` tinyint(3) unsigned DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`mid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

we use `iconv` to convert incoming email messages from incoming encoding to `utf-8//TRANSLIT` before saving to database. It works beautifully for all the languages except when we receive messages having Chinese characters.

Any idea?

Comment: Is UTF-8 really sufficient for Chinese ?

Comment: utf8mb4 should be sufficient for Chinese, I would think the issue lies at the conversion with iconv. Is it even necessary ? Also, the implementation of /TRANSLIT is system-dependent.

Comment: [U+E79A is not a valid unicode character.](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/e79a/index.htm) I think your input data may be malformed.

Comment: Also checked https://r12a.github.io/app-encodings/ and entered "E79A" into the bytes to decode field. It doesn't see to be a valid sequence in other encodings either.